# Why are my Bell pepper leaves deformed with contoured edges?

Tags: diagnosis, leaves, bell-peppers

I recently moved to a new apartment with a high balcony. It gets lots of sun, but also a lot of wind. Since I moved here about 1 month ago, my pepper plant leaves have started to become deformed (almost like an island undergoing erosion). I can't tell if it's because of pests, disease, or somehow the wind is causing it. None of the plants have flowered either, and I planted them from seed in mid-March (indoors, as we had a cold spring). What could be causing this issue?

Details:
I'm in southern Ontario, Canada and there are multiple plants growing from an outdoor planter which received new potting mix and some occasional fertilization. I've inspected the leaves but I haven't found any recent evidence of large pests.

[image][image]

Answer (score 3):

Any little insect nibble, injury will cause this deformity.  There is NOTHING wrong with your pepper that I can see.  Completely normal.  What are you fertilizing it with, what are your watering procedures, where is this plant?  Indoors, outdoors?  Is it flowering?  What kind of soil is this plant living in?

Went back to reread your question!  Exactly what kind of fertilizer have you been using?  If this pepper hasn't flowered yet the main reason would be TOO MUCH NITROGEN.  NPK. Those 3 numbers, if the N has a number larger than the P AND K, you will get lots of vegetative growth (leaves) and little to no reproductive growth (flowers, peppers)...